# WCF web app hosted on Azure error connection to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, azure, amazon-ec2

I hosted a WCF web application on Azure. It works perfectly on local. I can access to the web app but when I try to query the data from the azure web app it seems like it cannot connect to the SQL server containing the data which is located in an AWS ec2.
config.UseVerboseErrors is enabled so I receive this error when I try to get for example the top 5 of my entity:
http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/Dataservice.svc/Entity?$top=5

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn1YY.png)

Comment: It says at the bottom `Access is denied` - Do you need to add your IP or some accounts to a privileged/allow list?

Comment: I think that the AWS instance has some restrictions. I will replicate the database on Azure SQL and try to get the data from there.